# Solr: How to specify field relevancy/weight

Tags: search, solr

I'm currently indexing data using Solr that consists of about 10 fields. When I perform a search I would like certain fields to be weighted higher. Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

For example, searching across all fields for a term such as "superman" should return hits in the "`Title`" field before the "`Description`" field.

I've found documentation on how to make one field score higher from the query, but I would prefer to set this in a configuration file or similar. The following would require all searches to specify the weight. Is it possible to specify this in the `solr config` file?

```
q=title:superman^2 description:superman
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [qf with ExtendedDisMax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) your query then would look like that:

```
q=superman
```

While your config will look like:

```
<str name="qf">title^2 description</str>
```

You can get some working examples [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I was able to successfully configure the edismax parser and apply the appropriate weights - Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I need to change qf values in Java program but don't see any methods in SolrQuery object to do that, is there a different class for this?

Answer (score 3):

> The qf parameter introduces a list of fields, each of which is assigned a boost factor to increase or decrease that particular field's importance in the query. For example, the query below:
>
> ```
> qf="fieldOne^2.3 fieldTwo fieldThree^0.4"
> ```
>
> Assigns fieldOne a boost of 2.3, leaves fieldTwo with the default boost (because no boost factor is specified), and fieldThree a boost of 0.4. These boost factors make matches in fieldOne much more significant than matches in fieldTwo, which in turn are much more significant than matches in fieldThree."

Source: [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf_QueryFields_Parameter)

In your case: `qf="title^100 description"` may do the trick - if you're using Solr in a library I'd love to chat.

Answer (score 0):

By using [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) we can achieve what you looking for.

Try adding these two fields in your request handler by changing the fields.
You can remove a particular field completely, if you don't want it.

```
<str name="defType"> edismax </str>
<str name="qf"> YourField^50 YourAnotherField^30 YetAnotherField</str>
```

The more the power(^) increases, the more priority that field gets.